# what the function does?

Tags: arrays, c

```
#define SIZE 10 


void fun(int arr[]){
    int i,k,j,n = SIZE;
    k = 0;

    for (i = 1 ; i < SIZE; i++) {
        j = k;
        while (j > 0 && arr[j] != arr[i])
            j = j - 1;
        if( j == 0){
            k = k + 1;
            arr[k] = arr[i];
        }
        else
            n--;
    }
}
```

This function was in my test today.

My question is: does someone know what it does?
What does the variable n represent at the end of the function?

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: yes but i really not understand what it does @Thomas

Comment: Don't copy code from unknown sources unless they describe what the code does. Blindly copy-pasting unknown code leads to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) which is bad.

Comment: As for learning what a specific piece of code does, use common *debugging* techniques, like [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) or using an actual debugger to step through the code statement by statement.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: yeah i know but this function was in my test today and I did not understand at all what she is doing I tried to debug but it is not understood @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in this case (and for example generally in arduino programming) the voodoo programming term  is better (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the function, the variable `n` will have counted how many times each `i-th` array value in the range `[0, SIZE)` was unique among the first `i` array elements..

In addition, the first `n` elements of the array will contain exactly those elements that were found to be unique in the above sense. All other array entries will remain unchanged.

The other variables will have the following values:

```
i == SIZE
j == some value between [0, SIZE)
k == n-1
```

Some inline comments may help understand the code better.

```
#define SIZE 10 


void fun(int arr[]){
    int i,k,j,n = SIZE;
    k = 0;
    
    // walk through the array up until its 10th element, skipping
    // the first entry and hoping that the array actually contains 
    // at least 10 entries
    for (i = 1 ; i < SIZE; i++) {
        // similar to i, the variable k also walks up towards 10.
        // However it starts at 0, not at 1, and it does not 
        // necessarily get incremented in every loop iteration. More
        // on that below. 
        // Here, we set the variable j to start out as the same value
        // as the current k, but j will walk the opposite direction, i.e.,
        // toward 0, not toward 10.
        j = k;

        // find the largest j in the open interval [0,k) for which
        // the array entry arr[j] differs from the current arr[i] 
        while (j > 0 && arr[j] != arr[i])
            j = j - 1;

        // if no value in [0, k) was equal to arr[i], we'll end up \
        // with j == 0
        if( j == 0){
            // then we increment k -- that is, k counts how many times
            // we encountered a value arr[i] during the for-loop that was
            // unique among the first i array entries. But since the 
            // for loop starts at 1 instead of 0, k will count one
            // element too few.
            k = k + 1;

            // well, so much for 'unique': here, we actually copy the current
            // value arr[i] into arr[k]
            arr[k] = arr[i];
        }
        else
            // this part in effect assures that the expression
            // (n-k) gets decremented in every iteration of the loop,
            // no matter if j == 0 is true or false.
            // Since we start out with (n-k) = SIZE, and
            // the loop body gets executed SIZE-1 times, (n-k) will
            // be equal to 1 after the for-loop has terminated.
            n--;
    }
}
```